# Is 'declares to have' correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this phrase correct?

> The Contractor declares to have the exclusive right to authorise...

or should it be:

> The Contractor declares that it has the exclusive right to authorise...

Answer (score -1):

Your first sentence is grammatically correct. In your second one use 'impersonal IT' is wrong. Put 'he' instead. It would be nice. If by any chance you want to retain 'it' express it like this:

*The contractor declares that it is his exclusive right ...

Here 'it' is anaphoric in a pseudo cleft sentence. Pseudo cleft is the name given to a sentence which , otherwise straight forward, we cleave  into two halves to lay intended stress on something. Your examples are case in point.

However if it refers to a company then the issue is different. There might have been no need of asking the question.

Comment: "The Contractor" may be an *it* if the contractor is a corporate entity rather than a person.

Comment: Ok, but "It" is used purposefully because the contractor is a company (impersonal), not an individual...

Comment: That's a point but still 'it' is a misfit. Get rid of 'contractor' instead.

Comment: Context would be of help. Company is a 'legal person'. In that case 'it' will do. In our parts we are in the habit of using 'they'.

Comment: What am I missing? Neither phrase is correct and might we always leave out irrelevances such as *… the exclusive right to authorise...* except when they make a difference.

No-one can *declare to have* anything. The closest he or it could come would be to *declare himself to have* or, yes, *declare that it has*, which constructions match special situations such as *Anything to declare* at Customs barriers, not everyday English.

Contractors *argue over/claim/insist on/maintain/legislate on the basis of* but never *declare* a right.

*Declaration* is not a property of *rights*.